# Check if strings char matches 100% char array?

Tags: c#

is there a good way to check if a string contain 100% char array, The same chars can be there multible times.

char array:

```
private static char[] Letter = { 'd', 'o' , 'g' };
```

so it would match:

```
string a = "dog"
string b = "dooooggg"
```

but wouldn't match`

```
string c = "doig"
```

and if trying to be really specific, can i descripe how many of each char there can be in the string to match?

Comment: Does the order matter? i.e. does "god" match

Comment: God should match aswell, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Intersect`, `Take` and `Count`, supporting a min-match-count as desired:

```
char[] Letter = { 'd', 'o', 'g' };
int minMatchCount = 2;

string a = "dog";      // 3 matches, fine
string b = "dooooggg"; // 3 matches, fine
string c = "dock";     // 2 matches, fine
string d = "foo";      // nope, only 1

bool minMatchingA = a.Intersect(Letter).Take(minMatchCount).Count() == minMatchCount; // true
bool minMatchingB = b.Intersect(Letter).Take(minMatchCount).Count() == minMatchCount; // true
bool minMatchingC = c.Intersect(Letter).Take(minMatchCount).Count() == minMatchCount; // true
bool minMatchingD = d.Intersect(Letter).Take(minMatchCount).Count() == minMatchCount; // false
```

If you want to know if all characters are contained set `minMatchCount` to `Letter.Length`.

Comment: Thanks, i will test it out.

Answer (score 5):

Approach with `Linq`

```
char[] Letter = { 'd', 'o', 'g' };
string b = "dooooggg";

bool result = b.All(Letter.Contains);
```